# Python dictionary with len(20) compare to list with range(7804)

Tags: python, dictionary

I have been trying to convert an xml file into CSV file format. 
    And now I have a small problem. Which is the if else statement of printing it into csv files.

This is what I have

I have a dictionary with the len of 20.

```
Rankings{4706: '8.185', 2358: '0.444', 6245: '0.851', 615: '0.444', 7626: '2.164', 2219: '0.315', 4338: '0.348', 3790: '0.876', 6194: '0.362', 2228: '0.541', 597: '0.495', 6838: '3.883', 4567: '1.173', 7800: '0.521', 3796: '0.326', 2042: '5.076', 5141: '0.316', 1722: '0.595', 5566: '0.555', 1429: '0.435'}
```

And I have few list that is 7804 big.

```
eventIDList = []
artKeyList = []
languageAll = []
startDateTime = []
endDateTime = []
sentenceID = []
sentenceContent = []
```

I use the dictionaryKey to compare with the eventIDList so that if it's the same, it will print the value of the key into the csv file.

So I have tried using

```
for a in rankings:
    for i in range(7804):
           if(int(a) == int(eventIDList[i])):
                    csvFile.write(eventIDList[i] + ',' + ...... +',' + rankings[a])
           else:
                    csvFile.write(eventIDList[i] + ',' + ..... + ',' + " "(rankings) + ',' + sentenceContent[i])
```

The problem is that the program only go through the if statement. But i still need it to go through the else statement.

Any idea where went wrong in my codes?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "still need it to go through the else statement". Please clarify. Seems like you could just remove the `else` and un-indent the following line so it will execute regardless of whether the `if` conditional is true or not.

Comment: Please, explain more on what do you mean by "But i still need it to go through the else statement.".

Comment: Hi, i have tried removing the else statement and un-indent the following line. It will print out everything. but it will print out multiple times. For eg, i should have 7804 lines into total in my .csv files. But now i got 156101 lines instead due to the nested loops. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: You'll get 156101 lines, because you are iterating ranking's keys times 7804 elements and when loop finishes, append a extra line (7804*20 + 20 = 156100 [+1 new line]). Take a look to the answer, and tell me if it help you

Comment: Try to come up with a *minimal* example that still exhibits the incorrect behavior. (The same loop, but with lists of no more than ten elements.) You will most likely solve the problem in the process of preparing the minimal example and, if not, we will be much more equipped to help you.

Comment: Yes, i understand what you are trying to say. WHat are the possible solution for me to do so that it won't loop another 20 times more?

Comment: I think the op means to say that the "else" clause is never entered, i.e. something is wrong with the test expression.

Comment: you might want to check out the `csv` module, it could make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

If all arrays have the same length, and your output must be a line per array position, your loop should look like this

```
eventIDList = range(7804)
sentenceContent = range(7804)
rankings = {4706: '8.185', 2358: '0.444', 6245: '0.851', 615: '0.444', 7626: '2.164', 2219: '0.315', 4338: '0.348', 3790: '0.876', 6194: '0.362', 2228: '0.541', 597: '0.495', 6838: '3.883', 4567: '1.173', 7800: '0.521', 3796: '0.326', 2042: '5.076', 5141: '0.316', 1722: '0.595', 5566: '0.555', 1429: '0.435'}
for idx in range(len(eventIDList)):
    if rankings.get(idx,'') and eventIDList[idx] == rankings.get(idx,''):
         csvFile.write( "%i, %s" % (eventIDList[idx] , rankings[idx]))
    else:
        csvFile.write( "%i, %i" % (eventIDList[idx] , sentenceContent[idx]))
```

Comment: Hi, my arrays are the same length. Just that my dictionary.Key is different with the length of 20 only. But i need to compare the length of my dictionary to the length of a list which is 7804.

Comment: Wich values has eventIDList?

Comment: the eventIDList is just a list with 7804 elements inside. the elements are from 1 to 7804.

Comment: Maybe there's a parse error when you are generating the string that will be writed in csv file. I've changed that line by a print statement and TypeError is raised:         
>>> print (eventIDList[idx] + ','+ rankings[idx])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Try my last edit